# find solutions that solve the equations

Tags: rsa

I am implementing a timing attack on RSA for school and I need to generate two sets of messages $Y$ and $Z$ for which holds:

$ (Y^d \mod N) \cdot Y < N $ and
$ (Z^d \mod N) \cdot Z > N $

where $d$ and $N$ are known. How can I efficiently find solutions for $Y$ and $Z$?

I have tried using a random function but it takes too long to complete or it doesn't complete at all.

Comment: I agree with @CodesInChaos .  If we assume $d$ is random, then $Y=k$ has probability $1/k$ of working; likely there is a small $Y$ that would work (and starting at the smallest and working your way up seems like the obvious approach (unless, of course, $Y=0$ or $Y=1$ isn't disallowed for some reason).

Comment: Do you have a typo in the condition for $Z$? The $*Z>Z$ part is weird.

Comment: yes there was a typo in the Z condition. thanks i have corrected it.

Comment: For Z, try any Z > N/2; that should work.

Comment: You state $d$ is known.  By convention, $d$ stands for the private exponent (which is one of the targets if you're trying to recover the private key; if you get that, you've won).  Do you really mean the private exponent $d$?  Or, do you really mean the public exponent (and are using nonstandard terminology to describe it)?

Comment: d is a partial private exponent which was already recovered with the timing attack.

Comment: Oh, if you've recovered one of the CRT exponents (say, $d \bmod p$), then the rest is easy; see the answer in http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/exposing-rsa-private-key-data-bad

Comment: i am not using CRT but a simple square and multiply (just a simple demonstration of a simple timing attack). d is a binary number of the already recovered bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding a $Z$ is easy. This condition is fulfilled for all $Z>n/2$, and most of the smaller values of $Z$ too. There are only a few values fulfilling the condition for $Y$, and since this is almost the negation of the condition for $Y$, most numbers will fulfill it.

When looking at the condition for $Y$, you can model $Y^d \mod N$ as a random number between 0 and $N$.
This leads to a success chance of approximately $ 1/Y $.

Thus a good strategy for finding a $Y$ is starting with $ Y = 2 $ and incrementing by one on each attempt, i.e. trying 2, 3, 4,... This should find a number fulfilling $ (Y^d \mod N) \cdot Y < N $ quite quickly.

Total chance of finding an $ Y \le n$ is:

$1-\Pi^n_{i=2}(1-1/i) = $

$1 - \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = $

$ 1- 1/n $

Which quickly converges to 1

Comment: sorry there was a typo in the Z condition. For the Y condition - what would be a good increase on each attempt (N is 512bit at least)

Comment: @blejzz The best increase would be 1. You simply want to try the smallest $Y$s first, since those have the highest success chance.

Answer (score 2):

@CodesInChaos gives an excellent answer.

I'll add one more point: if you are not able to find a $Y$ satisfying your condition using CodesInChaos's approach, here is one more approach you can try as a fallback.

Pick a small value $i$, set $Y=i^e \pmod{N}$, and try $Y$.  Note that $Y^d \bmod N$ will be equal to $i$, and $Y$ can be modelled as a random number between 0 and $N$.  This means that you have a success chance of approximately $1/i$, with this strategy.

So, you can try $i=2$, $i=3$, $i=3$, \dots, in succession until you find the first success.  By the same argument CodesInChaos gives, there is likely to be a small $i$ for which this succeeds.

Again, this doesn't really add anything.  There is no particular reason to prefer this strategy over CodesInChaos's, if both $e$ and $d$ are known.  However, this is available as a fallback if CodesInChaos's method fails.  Also, this method is available if $d$ is not known but $e$ is known.